# Condicionar un buscarv

Tags: excel

Tengo un libro de excel que se llena diariamente con las actividades y tiempo de horas laborales que tomo realizar dicha actividad y el código del estudio y lo vincule a otro libro que contiene las mismas actividades pero separado por 3 tablas que indican las etapas en las que va el estudio(SETUP, CONDUCT,CLOSEOUT), lo que hice primero fue que las horas que me daba el reporte de tareas diario llenara automáticamente las horas de trabajo del otro excel que esta dividido por fases usando un `buscarv` con una tabla dinámica para que al escribir la actividad en el reporte diario la encontrara en el otro libro y llenara la columna de las horas trabajadas, la situación es que hay nombres de actividades que se repiten en las tres etapas y lo que quiero es poder condicionar la formula que tengo para que no se repitan las horas y la actividad vaya en la tabla de etapa dependiendo el código, por ejemplo, el código DGR2022 esta en la etapa SETUP e hice la actividad "review R&P file" que se repite en la dos primeras etapas pero solo quiero que las horas que trabaje en dicha actividad salgan en SETUP y no en SETUP Y CONDUCT

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La imagen de abajo es el reporte de actividades diarias

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

su tabla dinamica

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta es la formula

```
=BUSCARV(C11,'[Daily time track_IU_Nov2022.xlsx]Hoja1'!$A$4:$B$15,2,FALSO)
```

Pensaba usar la tabla dinámica y la tabla normal donde dice study code para condicionar.

Si la actividad encontrada con `buscarv` tenia el código DAP2021-1 entonces se llenara la columna J que es de las horas para la etapa de CONDUCT pero tengo problemas con la sintaxis, no se como indicar la columna J y esto es lo que he intentado

```
=SI((BUSCARV(C11,'[Daily time track_IU_Nov2022.xlsx]Hoja1'!$A$4:$B$15,2,FALSO),'[Daily time track_IU_Nov2022.xlsx]IU'!$F$1 = "DAE20222-1");J)
```

Answer (score 0):

La sintaxis correcta de la formula seria la siguiente

> =SI('[Daily time track_IU_Nov2022.xlsx]IU'!$F$1 = "DBC2018-1",BUSCARV(H11,'[Daily time track_IU_Nov2022.xlsx]Hoja1'!$A$4:$B$15,2,FALSO),BUSCARV(H11,'[Daily time track_IU_Nov2022.xlsx]Hoja1'!$A$4:$B$15,2,FALSO))

Comment: ¿Esta es la respuesta buena o es el otro comentario?

Comment: Esta es la respuesta (: